# Was this character killed in the Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

Bane is seen hit by a motorcycle of sorts or possibly shot by the motorcycle but Bane has shown to be very formidable. I feel that a villain of his caliber would have a more conclusive death but his "defeat" was very anti climactic and had no epilogue.

Was he really killed?

Comment: But that in many ways makes his death more significant. Kyuzo in Seven Samurai pretty much just drops dead in the background of a scene. That might be one of the most epic deaths in cinema. Also, let's not forget those 40mm cannons also blasted a hole in the tunnel blockade. No human being hit by those direct enough to be thrown across a room would survive it no matter how formidable they are. It's surprising he wasn't ripped in two and half the building behind it destroyed as well since typically 40mm blast cannons are anti-aircraft grade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the plot synopsis on Wikipedia:

> As Bane is about to execute Batman with a shotgun, Selina crashes into the lobby on the Batpod and mortally wounds Bane by blasting him with the Pod's large cannons.

The ultimate way in which Bane is defeated might seem anti climatic but the defeat was certainly not undramatic. Retracing the events that led up to Bane's defeat show that he was indeed defeated after a lot of struggle on the hero's part. The long fight leading up to his defeat involves Batman damaging his life-support mask which results in Bane being in immense pain. This is achieved by his foe (Batman) who manages to overpower him despite having being heavily defeated by him in the past. Batman manages to face and defeat Bane after escaping an inescapable prison to which Bane himself had condemned him to.

Bane's real defeat was Batman being able to damage his life-support apparatus after which Bane could hardly fight back. Following that, the plot twist (involving Talia being revealed as working with Bane) brings out the new villain. Bane's "second" defeat thus would hold little significance since Talia is still at large and Gotham is still at the risk of annihilation at her hands. The main villain in the final few moments of the movie is thus Talia and not Bane and as such, a more dramatic defeat of Bane would have little significance.

Comment: First paragraph answers the question but everything after that doesn't support the first paragraph neither focused on what happened to bane **after** selina shot him

Comment: So, if the quote citing his 'mortal wounds' was from somewhere a little more solid than a user editable plot synopsis without a specified reference then we would be there...! The rest of the post is a fair (but still subjective) read on the conflict but as you state it has nowt to do with whether or not he actually survived...